# How can I use sed to remove the first paragraph of the file?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So the paragraph is defined by having a empty line at the end.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Nunc et nisi tristique, facilisis orci nec, pellentesque tortor. 

Suspendisse mattis,
```

would end up as

```
Nunc et nisi tristique, facilisis orci nec, pellentesque tortor. 

Suspendisse mattis,
```

Comment: you want to remove first paragraph only??

Comment: try this `awk 'NR>1{print $0}' file`

Comment: @Hackaholic that assumes that the first paragraph is a single line. The `{print $0}` is not needed by the way, you culd just do `awk 'NR>1' file`.

Comment: If you like `awk` try `awk 'a==1;/^$/{a=1}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a great `sed` approach so here's a Perl way:

```
$ perl -00ne 'print if $.>1' file
```

The `-00` turns on "paragraph mode" where a line is defined by `\n\n`. Then, we print only if the current line number (`$.`) is >1.

Comment: +1 A magical way to do it: `perl -p00e 'BEGIN{<>}' file`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to delete lines between addresses defined by `1` (the first line of the file) and `/^$/` (a regular expression defining an empty line)

```
sed  '1,/^$/ d' file
```